# Numerically solving the stiff (singular) system of differential equations of motion of a trebuchet

Tags: python, scipy, simulation, numerical-methods, differential-equations

So I've been looking into the maths on trebuchets and trying to simulate one to maybe look into optimizing the trebuchets' performance. I'm aware that this has been done before, but I wanted to give it a go on my own. So after reading the article "trebuchet mechanics" by Donald B. Siano (http://www.algobeautytreb.com/trebmath356.pdf), I sat down and did the calculations wrt. the Euler-Lagrange equations that Siano simply gets Fortran to do for him. I have checked my answers with the ones from the article and they do in fact match.

Now comes the problem. Whenever I try to solve these equations numerically in python I get nonsense solutions where the energy is not constant. This is evident from a plot of the energy as well as from my simulation where you notice "jumps" in the motion and the fact that the motion slows down. I have come to the conclusion that the system is rather stiff because of the factor **eff_I** that I divide with becomes quite small whenever **phi** and **psi** are close to **pi**. But since I have the beam inertia not equal to 0 this is not a singularity and shouldn't cause a problem.

How would you go about solving these DEs better than I already do? and maybe it is even possible to solve them with mb and thus Ib = 0 which would make phi=psi=pi a singularity as is done in the above mentioned article? I have included my code below.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy as sc
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from numpy import sin, cos
from scipy import integrate
import matplotlib.animation as animation

# Differential equations

def trebuchet_model(t, r0, *param):
    dtheta, theta, dphi, phi, dpsi, psi = r0
    l1, l2, l3, l4, l5, m1, m2, mb, d, Ib, g = param

    def gen_t(m, d1, d2, ang, dang):
        return m * d1 * sin(ang) * (g * cos(theta + ang) - d2 * (dtheta + dang) ** 2 + d1 * dtheta ** 2 * cos(ang))

    eff_I = Ib + m1 * (l1 * sin(phi)) ** 2 + m2 * (l2 * sin(psi)) ** 2
    eff_t = grav_t + gen_t(m1, l1, l4, phi, dphi) + gen_t(m2, -l2, -l3, psi, dpsi)
    grav_t = mb * g * d * sin(theta)

    ddtheta = eff_t / eff_I

    def ddang(d1, d2, ang):
        return (d1 * dtheta ** 2 * sin(ang) + (d1 * cos(ang) - d2) * ddtheta + g * sin(theta + ang)) / d2

    ddphi = ddang(l1, l4, phi)
    ddpsi = ddang(-l2, -l3, psi)

    return [ddtheta, dtheta, ddphi, dphi, ddpsi, dpsi]


# Solve the DEs using Scipy integrate module

l1, l2, l3, l4, l5, m1, m2, mb, g = 1, 3.75, 3.75, 1, 0, 133, 1, 3, 10
d, Ib = (l2 - l1) / 2, mb * (l1 ** 2 + l2 ** 2 - l1 * l2) / 3,
param = [l1, l2, l3, l4, l5, m1, m2, mb, d, Ib, g]
init_state = [0, 3 * np.pi / 4, 0, np.pi / 4, 0, -np.pi / 4]

times = np.linspace(0, 5, 500)
solution = sc.integrate.solve_ivp(lambda t, r0: trebuchet_model(t, r0, *param), (0, 5), init_state, t_eval=times, method="Radau")

# Compute Cartesian coordinates and system energy

dtheta, theta, dphi, phi, dpsi, psi = solution.y
ddtheta, ddphi, ddpsi = np.array(trebuchet_model(0, solution.y, *param))[np.array([0, 2, 4]), :]

def coords(d1, d2, theta, ang):
    x = d1 * sin(theta) - d2 * sin(theta + ang)
    y = - d1 * cos(theta) + d2 * cos(theta + ang)
    return (x, y)

x1, y1 = coords(l1, l4, theta, phi)
x1p, y1p = l1 * sin(theta), - l1 * cos(theta)
x2, y2 = coords(-l2, -l3, theta, psi)
x2p, y2p = - l2 * sin(theta), l2 * cos(theta)

def speed_sq(d1, d2, dtheta, dang, ang):
    return (d1 * dtheta) ** 2 + (d2 * (dtheta + dang)) ** 2 - 2 * d1 * d2 * dtheta * (dtheta + dang) * cos(ang)

v1sq = speed_sq(l1, l4, dtheta, dphi, phi)
v2sq = speed_sq(-l2, -l3, dtheta, dpsi, psi)
T = (m1 * v1sq + m2 * v2sq + Ib * dtheta ** 2) / 2
U = g * (m1 * y1 + m2 * y2 + mb * d * cos(theta))
H = T + U

# Plot energy and animate trebuchet

energy_fig = plt.figure("energy")
plt.plot(times, H, 'k-')

treb_fig = plt.figure("trebuchet")
ax = plt.axes(xlim=(-8, 8), ylim=(-6, 8))

ax.plot([0], [0], 'ko', markersize=2)
ax.plot([0, 0], [0, -5], 'k-')
swingarm, = ax.plot([], [], 'k-')
pivot_points, = ax.plot([], [], 'ko', markersize=2)
cw_arm, = ax.plot([], [], 'k-')
cw, = ax.plot([], 'ko', markersize=20)
sling, = ax.plot([], [], 'k-')
projectile, = ax.plot([], [], 'ko', markersize=8)
projectile_path, = ax.plot([], [], '--', color="gray")

def update(i):
    projectile_path.set_data([x2[:i]], [y2[:i]])
    swingarm.set_data([x1p[i], x2p[i]], [y1p[i], y2p[i]])
    pivot_points.set_data([x1p[i], x2p[i]], [y1p[i], y2p[i]])
    cw_arm.set_data([x1p[i], x1[i]], [y1p[i], y1[i]])
    cw.set_data([x1[i]], [y1[i]])
    sling.set_data([x2p[i], x2[i]], [y2p[i], y2[i]])
    projectile.set_data([x2[i]], [y2[i]])

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(treb_fig, update, 500, interval=10)
plt.show()
```

Comment: `Error: local variable 'grav_t' referenced before assignment` (in `eff_t = grav_t + gen_t(m1, l1,...`) and is also not defined elsewhere.